# How to list categories only related to enabled entries or disabled child entries

Tags: craft3, templating, entries, categories

**Edit: solved in comments**

My entries are set up as a parent > child structure. A single entry can either have children or not have any. If parent has children, the children entries are put in a disabled state, because those children should not show up as individual entries on the frontend, but are instead shown as subitems on a parent's entry page.

Then, a category is assigned to a level 1 entry if it has no children; and in case of level 2 children, the category is assigned to each child but none to its parent entry. Categories themselves are also set up in a parent > child structure. If a child category is assigned to an entry, its parent category also applies to that entry.

I'd like to output a categories list on the frontend which lists all categories assigned to any level of entry, as long as its parent entry has an enabled state in backend.

Example structure:

- [state: enabled] entry 1, category: A
- [state: enabled] entry 2, category: none

  - [state: disabled] entry 2.1, category: B
  - [state: disabled] entry 2.2, category: C
- [state: enabled] entry 3, category: A
- [state: enabled] entry 4, category: D
- [state: disabled] entry 5, category: none

  - [state: disabled] entry 5.1, category: E
  - [state: disabled] entry 5.2, category: F

I'm looking for the exact query to output A B C D because its parent entries are enabled, but not output E F because its parent entry is disabled.

So far I have this query but it is not considering the child entries' categories.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mysection').limit(null) %}
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('mycategories').orderBy("title asc").relatedTo(entries).find() %}

{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This does not answer your question, but if it's not too late I'd recommend you reconsider your approach here - the enabled/disabled state of an entry should not be abused in this way - you'll find yourself fighting against the system at every step. If the child entries should not be URL-addressable, redirect to the parent entry's URL in the template if `entry.level` is > 1. Don't disable them.

Comment: @JamesSmith Thank you, I had not considered this approach and tbh, I'm not even sure why I set it up the way I did. A quick test proves enabling the child entries likely fixes my issue. Now I'm struggling with the redirect code. How would I redirect a child's url to its parent url?

Comment: `{% if entry.level != 1 %}{% redirect entry.parent().url() %}{% endif %}`

Comment: Thanks, it really was that obvious and easy :)

Comment: Either one of you want to add the solution as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future? :)